# ongoing discussion on ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to do something kind of like chat, but not chat.
The scenario is as following:
3 people: A, B, and C are on the same page
A posts something on that page
B and C sees this posts without refreshing (the page partially refreshes on its own without post back)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is not really clear to me, what problems are you running into and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will be some kind of callback using Javascript. A complete sample can be found here: http://www.geekbeing.com/2012/05/18/implement-live-web-chat-part-1

Comment: Oh this seems just what I need. Thanks, I'll see it now